# MVC Error when opening a project from TFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have created an asp.net MVC application in VS 2010, and am using TFS.

When another programmer opened my application from TFS and tries to run it (he is also using VS 2010)

He gets an error saying type or namespace MVC cannot be found in System.web

what do we need to do to get this to build on his machine?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the references in his project, there should be one for System.Web.Mvc, sounds like it is missing.

For completeness, given he has 2010 installed, to add he can right click on references and select System.Web.Mvc dll from the .NET tab.

Comment: Thank you! That lead me to the problem. For some reason Mine was referencing MVC 1.0 and he only has MVC 2.0 I changed the reference so it was MVC 2.0 and we are good. Thanks!